# How to recover Call Record information from MS Teams via Graph API

Tags: azure, graph, microsoft-teams, phone-call, azure-ad-msal

We have a stand alone process which needs to get call record details of completed calls via the Graph API.

We have obtained record IDs via the Azure Dashboard so that we can use them with the following endpoint

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{id}
```

as shown in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

The Azure App has been configured for access and has readAll permissions set.
The following code generates a token for access, but when actually trying to read back a call record specified by id, it always returns 404 Not found.

```
            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientID)
                                                      .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                      .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                                                      .Build();

            var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

            string id = "YYYYYYYY-F571-45D9-ABC6-XXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Real ID, but obfuscated for this example  
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/" + id));
```

Can anyone advise what I am missing.
Thanks

Comment: Do you need "grant_type", "client_credentials"
Are you sure you have the correct token?

Comment: I am still not sure how you retrieved the id.